# Failed to read netcdf file attribute, since the attribute name contains parentheses

Tags: python, python-2.7, netcdf

I am using python-2.7 and NetCDF4 module to read a netcdf file. I need to read a global attribute (`Lat(Degrees.Cents_of_degrees)`) from the netcdf file which contains parentheses in its name, but I can't read it. What I do:

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset as NetCDFFile
filename = 'DDE30.2002.RG300004.nc'
nc = NetCDFFile(filename)
lat = nc.Lat(Degrees.Cents_of_degrees)
```

But I get this:

```
AttributeError: NetCDF: Attribute not found
```

I have tried using backslash before the parentheses but doesn't work. [Here](https://anu365-my.sharepoint.com/personal/u5283635_uds_anu_edu_au/_layouts/15/guestaccess.aspx?guestaccesstoken=NTIIkF8lotZ6vk4uM53WS8gC1OvCsT7IWh2aaJfKSeI%3D&docid=018d32caee43642e68765dfca93228c2c) is the netcdf file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want `getncattr` [[docs]](http://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/#netCDF4.Dataset.getncattr). Probably best not to depend on the private method suggested by @M.T.

```
lat = nc.getncattr('Lat(Degrees.Cents_of_degrees)')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a hack which should work for your case, but which I do not recommend generalizing. When you access an attribute of the netCDF file using `nc.myattribute`, under the hood you are calling `nc.__getattribute__('myattribute')` (see the [documentation](https://netcdf4-python.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/netCDF4.Dataset-class.html)). As you can see, the input attribute is here a string, and it is therefore more permissive when it comes to allowed values. The undescores in the method name indicate that the authors of this library did not want to expose this functionality.

Thus, what you could do is:

```
lat = nc.__getattribute__('Lat(Degrees.Cents_of_degrees)')
```

Which will assign `44.120147251339418` to `lat`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. @M.T ! It was driving me crazy, but I didn't look at the problem from the root as you did. Great help :)

Comment: Indeed this is a hack.  There is a proper `getattr` method.  See my answer for more details.